# LSTM project not compatible with CSV format

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to replicate Chevalier's [LSTM Human Activity Recognition](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition/blob/master/LSTM.ipynb) algorithm and came across a problem when I was trying to implement my own data in a CSV format. The format used in the git was txt. My CSV data is of the following format:

```
0.000995,8
0.020801,8
0.040977,8
0.060786,8
0.080970,8
...            ...
```

The original file can be found [here](https://github.com/Jrachman/debug/blob/master/data_train.csv). The x-values (time) are in column 0 (-80.060003, etc.) and the y-values (value) are in column 1 (8, 8, etc.). I tried to use pandas

```
pandas.read_csv(DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + "data_train.csv", skiprows=1, header=None, sep=',', usecols=[0, 1])
```

but it does not seem to be compatible with the format of the data in the "Prepare Dataset" section (and possibly others as well):

```
TRAIN = "train/"
TEST = "test/"

# Load "X" (the neural network's training and testing inputs)

def load_X(X_signals_paths):
    X_signals = []

    for signal_type_path in X_signals_paths:
        file = open(signal_type_path, 'r')
        # Read dataset from disk, dealing with text files' syntax
        X_signals.append(
            [np.array(serie, dtype=np.float32) for serie in [
                row.replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ') for row in file
            ]]
        )
        file.close()

    return np.transpose(np.array(X_signals), (1, 2, 0))

X_train_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + "Inertial Signals/" + signal + "train.txt" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]
X_test_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TEST + "Inertial Signals/" + signal + "test.txt" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]

X_train = load_X(X_train_signals_paths)
X_test = load_X(X_test_signals_paths)


# Load "y" (the neural network's training and testing outputs)

def load_y(y_path):
    file = open(y_path, 'r')
    # Read dataset from disk, dealing with text file's syntax
    y_ = np.array(
        [elem for elem in [
            row.replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ') for row in file
        ]], 
        dtype=np.int32
    )
    file.close()

    # Substract 1 to each output class for friendly 0-based indexing 
    return y_ - 1

y_train_path = DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + "y_train.txt"
y_test_path = DATASET_PATH + TEST + "y_test.txt"

y_train = load_y(y_train_path)
y_test = load_y(y_test_path)
```

This was what is happening with my implementation via iPython3:

**In[0]:**

```
TRAIN = "train/"
TEST = "test/"

def load_X(X_signals_paths):
    X_signals = []
    for signal_type_path in X_signals_paths:
        file = pandas.read_csv(DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + "data_train.csv", skiprows=1, header=None, sep=',', usecols=[0])
        X_signals.append(
            [np.array(serie, dtype=np.float32) for serie in [
                str(row).replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ') for row in file
            ]]
        )

    return np.transpose(np.array(X_signals), (1, 2, 0))

_train_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + signal + "train.csv" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]
X_test_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TEST + signal + "test.csv" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]

X_train = load_X(X_train_signals_paths)
X_test = load_X(X_test_signals_paths)
print(X_train, X_test)
```

**Out[0]:**

```
[[[ 0.]]] [[[ 0.]]]
```

I hope that I could receive some help with properly formatting my data to work seamlessly with this algorithm. If there are any questions please let me know.

Comment: please provide the error message

Comment: @Paddy let me add something to my question and it should help

Comment: Your `pandas_read()` works here with the data you provided: `[892 rows x 2 columns]`

Comment: @tripleee It "works." But look at the output.

Comment: @Paddy The edit has been made at the end

Comment: Why are you attempting to remove spaces which aren't there anyway?

Comment: @tripleee Here?: str(row).replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ')

Comment: That doesn't look correct at all.  What do you want to end up in `X_signals`?

Comment: `[row for row in file]` produces `[0, 1]` so everything after that is just fluff. (Also maybe don't call your variables `file` because that shadows a builtin.)

Comment: @tripleee wait no it is not time. x are the values that trigger the classification events in y so the x would be column 1 right? i think time is just assumed somewhere where they are just overlapping equal-incremented time intervals.

Comment: also why the downvote? at least tell me what i need to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the trace differs from the code you actually posted in the question -- the working code is operating on a bare file handle, not a Pandas data frame.

For reference, here is the code from the project you are referring to again:

```
def load_X(X_signals_paths):
    X_signals = []

    for signal_type_path in X_signals_paths:
        file = open(signal_type_path, 'r')
        # ^ the error comes where you have file = pandas.read_csv(...)

        # Read dataset from disk, dealing with text files' syntax
        X_signals.append(
            [np.array(serie, dtype=np.float32) for serie in [
                row.replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ') for row in file
            ]]
        )
        file.close()
```

`file` is just an iterator which returns a raw line (a sequence of characters) ending with a newline; on this input, it makes sense to strip newlines and squeeze spaces.  But your code already opens, parses, and reformats the contents of the file into a Pandas data frame, which doesn't have newlines or spaces, just the numbers already parsed.  Maybe fall back to the upstream code; or if there is something you want to change in there, figure out how to ask about that change.  There's nothing wrong with the CSV as such.

Python has a quite capable [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) so maybe simply use that instead of manually parsing out the individual fields from the CSV.

```
    for signal_type_path in X_signals_paths:
        with open(signal_type_path, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            X_signals.append([np.array(row[0:2], dtype=np.float32) for row in reader])
```

Or as a minimal change, split on commas instead of spaces. (Your data looks like you don't actually need to remove spaces then.)

Also, tangentially, your code hardcodes the file it reads.  It's probably better to keep the `DATASET_PATH` and `TRAIN` parameters entirely in the calling code, and have `load_X` simply accept a list of full file paths, which it accepts without modifying them in any way.

Comment: The Github project you linked to and which apparently you are trying to adapt.

Comment: So you are saying for me to reformat my question again? I have already tried looking at the example code and dat formatting

Comment: No, this is an answer pointing out that the code in your error message differs from the code which actually works, and suggesting you undo that change.

Comment: so try open(data_train.csv, 'r')? Basically i am being asked the revert back to the open function?

Comment: That's the library, yeah.  You want to use it so that the end result is compatible with what the caller expects, obviously, but that should not be hard.