# Misunderstanding of LSTM time-based data preparation

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, machine-learning, tensorflow

I am trying to replicate Chevalier's [LSTM Human Activity Recognition](https://github.com/guillaume-chevalier/LSTM-Human-Activity-Recognition/blob/master/LSTM.ipynb) algorithm and came across a problem when I realized that my methods did not match that of the algorithm. As a follow-up from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45006397/lstm-project-not-compatible-with-csv-format), I was able to produce a result for `load_X` by this method:

**In[0]:**

```
def load_X(X_signals_paths):
    X_signals = []
    for signal_type_path in X_signals_paths:
        with open(signal_type_path, 'r') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            next(reader)
            for serie in [row[1:2] for row in reader]:
            #X_signals.append([np.array([row[1:2] for row in reader],dtype=np.float32) for row in reader])
                X_signals.append(np.array(serie, dtype=np.int32))
            file.close()
    return (np.transpose(np.transpose(X_signals), (1, 0)))

X_train_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + signal + "_train.csv" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]
X_test_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TEST + signal + "_test.csv" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]

X_train = load_X(X_train_signals_paths)
X_test = load_X(X_test_signals_paths)
print(X_train)
```

**Out[0]:**

```
[[ 6]
 [ 6]
 ..., 
 [13]
 [13]
 [13]]
```

However I looked over Chevalier's methods a little more and I observed something interesting when I did `len(X_train[0])` and `len(X_train[0][0])`. It seems the way I formatted my x-values is much different than how Chevalier's x-values are. My original CSV file can be found [here](https://github.com/Jrachman/debug/blob/master/data_train.csv) and the original txt file for Chevalier's X_train can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8gnwkou4drp3tt/X_train.txt?dl=0). The following is Chevalier's code for comparison to mine:

```
def load_X(X_signals_paths):
    X_signals = []

    for signal_type_path in X_signals_paths:
        file = open(signal_type_path, 'r')
        # Read dataset from disk, dealing with text files' syntax
        X_signals.append(
            [np.array(serie, dtype=np.float32) for serie in [
                row.replace('  ', ' ').strip().split(' ') for row in file
            ]]
        )
        file.close()

    return np.transpose(np.array(X_signals), (1, 2, 0))

X_train_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TRAIN + "Inertial Signals/" + signal + "train.txt" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]
X_test_signals_paths = [
    DATASET_PATH + TEST + "Inertial Signals/" + signal + "test.txt" for signal in INPUT_SIGNAL_TYPES
]

X_train = load_X(X_train_signals_paths)
X_test = load_X(X_test_signals_paths)
```

The following is from Chevalier's "Additional Parameters" section and is the main reason for my confusion:

```
training_data_count = len(X_train)  # 7352 training series (with 50% overlap between each serie)
test_data_count = len(X_test)  # 2947 testing series
n_steps = len(X_train[0])  # 128 timesteps per series
n_input = len(X_train[0][0])  # 9 input parameters per timestep
```

What I observe is that this 50% overlap means that the separate evaluated time intervals are overlapping like 0-64, 32-96, 64-128, 96-etc. One fact that I do know is that 7352 is the number of rows in X_train.txt. The `[0]` and `[0][0]` mean that it is selecting the 0th column of the X_train array and the 0th column and 0th row of X_train respectively. What my code is currently doing is transposing each of my data points individually. That is why when I evaluated `len(X_train[0])` I received a 1 and with `len(X_train[0][0])` I received an error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-14523e544e49> in <module>()
      2 test_data_count = len(list(X_test))
      3 n_steps = len(X_train[0])
----> 4 n_input = len(list(X_train)[0][0])
      5 print(training_data_count, test_data_count, n_steps, n_input)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

I am wondering what I should do to reformat my data to match the intended formatting of Chevalier in the txt file? What do the numbers in the "Additional Parameters" section of the Chevalier's git mean and how can I tailor them to my current model?

Comment: It looks like Chevalier's data file has one event (561 measurement points) on each line, while your data looks like it's all a single event (893 points). Is this a correct observation? In addition, yours are monotonically increasing while theirs seem like relative measurements. We don't know what's in your data so we can't really guess how to reformat it, though.

Comment: There are some stylistic issues with your Python code.  You don't `close` a file handle you opened with `with` because the `with` context manager takes care of this for you. If you want to skip the first line of the CSV, you can tell the `reader` this by passing it a parameter.

Comment: Reading and then transposing seems rather inefficient.  Instead, just append your data points to the inner list.

Comment: @tripleee Your observation is right. I think it would be better if you wrote out a complete answer